# Eevee outputs large sections of video completely black

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, error

I'm trying to render a short 8 second mp4 animation loop, but for some reason Eevee keeps replacing large sections of the outputted video with complete blackness. Some of it renders the way I want, but then the rest is just black.. I've looked through the settings and I can't find anything that looks like it would cause that, and I have only two animation keyframes to make the camera move, nothing that would affect lighting. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I fiddled some more and fixed the problem. Turns out I had broken image files in the video sequencer that were overwriting it. In case anyone else has this issue, try rendering it with the sequencer bypassed. Hope this helps someone!